# Wrap li's content in a tag

Tags: jquery, forms, hyperlink, html-lists

I am using this plugin: http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/
And i need the li's content to be wrap in `<a href=""></a>`

```
<ul id="js-news">
    <li class="news-item">This is text 1 ...</li>
    <li class="news-item">This is text 2 ...</li>
    <li class="news-item">This is text 3 ...</li>
    <li class="news-item">This is text 4 ...</li>
 </ul>
```

like so:

```
<ul id="js-news">
        <li class="news-item"><a href="my-form">This is text 1 ...</a></li>
          <li class="news-item"><a href="my-form">This is text 2 ...</a></li>
          <li class="news-item"><a href="my-form">This is text 3 ...</a></li>
          <li class="news-item"><a href="my-form">This is text 4 ...</a></li>
</ul>
```

I thing the string needs to be in this one. But i dont know how:

```
script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#js-news').ticker({



        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: why cant the user edit the li's in the cms?

Comment: @Kasper Wrapping li element inside anchor tag will be semantically incorrect.

Comment: @freebird I'm pretty sure it's valid HTML5 though, but in this case it would be better to put the `a` inside the `li`

Comment: @jtheman: The end user dose not have eny clue how to do it.

Comment: @freebird: Not the li but the content inside the li

Comment: @Kasper You mean you want to set li's text as anchor tag's text,is ti?

Comment: @freebird: Yes, and the anchor tag have to link to a popup form

Comment: @Kasper How many links should be generated , should it be equal to li elements?

Comment: Only one en every li element. I edit my question maby it make more sens?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$('li.news-item').each(function(){
  $(this).contents().wrap('<a href="#"/>');
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/uqedeq/1/edit

Comment: I do not think you need to iterate through the elements in the selection.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, as long as your users won't/can't insert their own link elements:

```
$('li.news-items').contents().wrap('<a href="#" />');​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TvaNm/).

Comment: It works at some point, But i think i have to incorporate in this

`$('#js-news').ticker(
 
 );`

Becuse i im using this plugin:http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/
But i have tried for some time now and i can't get it to work..